# Show/hide element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add/remove a class of an element by clicking on a header. The problem I am facing is that the div I am targeting to show does not have an unique class, no ID and is on the same level as the header I am clicking on:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
       <h4 class="panel-title">
           <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#text-background" data-parent="#settings-accordeon" class="collapsed">achtergrond</a>
       </h4>
    </div>    
    <div id="text-background" class="panel-collapse collapse">
~~ Something in in it.
    </div>
</div>
```

I have 4 of these divs below each other.

I am trying to find the right selector in jQuery to be able to do the following:

1. Click on div with class: "panel-heading"
2. Select the div with the class: "panel-collapse collapse"
3. Add a class to this div called: "in"

This is what I got so far:

```
$('.panel-heading').click(function() {
    $('.panel-collapse').addClass('in');
});
```

But because I have multiple div's with this class, it opens them all...

Comment: Use unique ids instead of panel-collapse class.

Comment: You can use like -> $this.parent.child('.panel-collapse').addclass() --- you will have to twink this a little

Comment: Most of the answers offered to you are fine except, instead of using `addClass("in")` use `toggleClass("in")`.

Comment: Try `$(this).closest('.panel-collapse')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now you can try to this

```
$('.panel-heading').click(function() {
   $('.panel-collapse').removeClass('in');
    $(this).next('.panel-collapse').addClass('in');
    });
```

Demo

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('.panel-heading').click(function() {
       $('.panel-collapse').removeClass('in');
        $(this).next('.panel-collapse').addClass('in');
        }); 
});
```

```css
.in{background:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
       <h4 class="panel-title">
           <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#text-background" data-parent="#settings-accordeon" class="collapsed">achtergrond</a>
       </h4>
    </div>    
    <div id="text-background" class="panel-collapse collapse">
~~ Something in in it.
    </div>
  
  <div class="panel-heading">
       <h4 class="panel-title">
           <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#text-background" data-parent="#settings-accordeon" class="collapsed">achtergrond</a>
       </h4>
    </div>    
    <div id="text-background" class="panel-collapse collapse">
~~ Something in in it.
    </div>
  
  
  <div class="panel-heading">
       <h4 class="panel-title">
           <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#text-background" data-parent="#settings-accordeon" class="collapsed">achtergrond</a>
       </h4>
    </div>    
    <div id="text-background" class="panel-collapse collapse">
~~ Something in in it.
    </div>
  
  
  <div class="panel-heading">
       <h4 class="panel-title">
           <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#text-background" data-parent="#settings-accordeon" class="collapsed">achtergrond</a>
       </h4>
    </div>    
    <div id="text-background" class="panel-collapse collapse">
~~ Something in in it.
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help

```
$('.panel-collapse.collapse').addClass('in');
```

This will only select the element which have both `panel-collapse` and `collapse` class .

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
$('.panel-heading').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.panel-collapse').addClass('in');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this` to refer current selector

**jQuery**

```
$('.panel-heading').click(function() {
   $(this).siblings('.panel-collapse.collapse').addClass('in');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to select an element at the same level, you can use `.next()` function like this:

```js
$('.panel-heading').on('click', function() {
  $(this).next('.panel-collapse.collapse').addClass('in');
});
```

```css
.in {  
  padding:10px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
       <h4 class="panel-title">
           <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#text-background" data-parent="#settings-accordeon" class="collapsed">achtergrond</a>
       </h4>
    </div>    
    <div id="text-background" class="panel-collapse collapse">
~~ Something in in it.
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `next` since the div of class `panel-collapse collapse` is a direct sibling to the `panel-heading` div, also use toggleClass which is better in your case:

```
$('.panel-heading').click(function() {
    $(this).next('div').toggleClass('in');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this selector instead

```
$('.panel .panel-collapse:first-child').addClass('in');
```

Or

```
$('.panel-heading').next('.panel-collapse').addClass('in);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code to apply to the immediate sibling of `.panel-heading` only as such:

```
$('.panel-heading').click(function() {
     $(this).siblings('.panel-collapse').addClass('in');
});
```

*Note the usage of `this` with refers to the element that raised the event (i.e. `click` event).*

Answer (score 0):

Basically you just need to find the current elements next sibling and add a class to it:

```
$('.panel-heading').click(function() {
    $(this).next().addClass('in');
});
```

That will work if the panel-collapse is always after you panel-heading, else to be safe, you can do:

```
$('.panel-heading').click(function() {
    $(this).next(".panel-collapse").addClass('in');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the reference of the clicked div and try this code :-

```
 $('.panel-heading').click(function() {
  $(this).next('.panel-collapse').addClass('in');
 });
```

Hope this will work with your case.